# I'm trying to connect my homestead with Sql Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, homestead

I'm trying to install my homestead with sql server. 
i installed `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase`
i configure my .env

```
config/database.php
       'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'utp'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret123'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

.env
    DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=1433
    DB_DATABASE=utp
    DB_USERNAME=sa
    DB_PASSWORD=secret123
```

display this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o59H.jpg

Comment: Read the error message, it's right there. "Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes." Now look at your DB_PASSWORD.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You've tagged SQL Server and mention SQL Server in the question, but have installed Sybase drivers and your configuration is written for MySQL. Which is correct?

Comment: Please try to copy&paste the error message into your post (at the beginning of a line following a `> ` to make it a _block quote_).

Comment: yes i installed the correct driver, i put in my post

Comment: okay i changed my password to access my sql server is without space, but i cannot access not yet. Display this  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does n
  ot exist (severity 9)

Comment: i found the answer 
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'LPT-72227-DDS16'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'utp'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret123'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],